# Create Generic Realm repository in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, realm

I have been struggling with solving a problem which I am pretty sure leads me to adopt the Type-Erasure technique but I am not 100% sure. I have tried several different times and have felt close but ultimately have failed. I will try to simplify my problem. Lets say you have an entity

```
struct Expense {
    var id: Int?
    var amount: Double = 0
}
```

and an equivalent Realm Object

```
class RealmExpense: Object {
    let id = RealmOptional<Int>()
    let amount = RealmOptional<Double>()

    var entity: Expense {
        return Expense(id: id.value, amount: amount.value)
    }
}
```

Note that I can convert from RealmExpense to Expense by using the entity variable.

Then, I have another protocol

```
protocol ExpenseRepository: class {
    func getAll() -> [Expense]
    //...other CRUD methods
}
```

and finally, a class

```
class ExpenseRealmRepository: ExpenseRepository {
    
    private let realm = try! Realm()
    
    func getAll() -> [Expense] {
        return realm.objects(RealmExpense.self).flatMap { $0.entity }
    }

    func insert(item: Expense) {
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(RealmExpense(expense: item))
        }
    }
    //...implementation of other CRUD methods
}
```

Now, this works fine, but I have many entities, and this is repetitive code that I would like to refactor but every attempt I have made to make this generic throws one compiler error or another. What I would like is to basically be able to create a class

```
class RealmRepository<RepositoryType: Object, EntityType> {

    private let realm = try! Realm()

    func getAll() -> [EntityType] {
        return realm.objects(RepositoryType.self).flatMap { $0.entity }
    }

    func insert(item: EntityType) {
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(RepositoryType(item))
        }
    }
    //...the rest of the CRUD methods.
}
```

My main problem is that it seems that Swift generics do not allow this type of behavior. Maybe there is a better overall approach that I have not explored.

#### Note: Small addendum to Dave Weston's answer below:

The answer given by David Weston below is correct (and excellent) but there is currently a Swift bug that prevents the Realm Entity initializer from being used. See:

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/2514

Basically, the solution is to use the default initializer for Realm Objects which accept a dictionary. Since I am already using the ObjectMapper library to convert entities to and from JSON this was as simple as changing

```
func insert(item: T.EntityType) {
    realm.write {
        realm.add(RealmEntityType(item))   //compiler error when initializing RealmEntityType
    }
}
```

to

```
func insert(item: T.EntityType) {
    let realmItem = RealmEntityType()         
    realmItem.setValuesForKeys(item.toJSON())  //needs to be a dictionary
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(realmItem)
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use this syntax to create generics for realm for example: `func saveInRealm<T: Object>(object: T) { try! realm.write { realm.add(object)}} `

Comment: Yes but the point of using the repository is to abstract away the fact that T is a Realm Object. T should be a pure swift struct or class so this would not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was an interesting problem. I'm not sure how you'll be using these repository objects, but based on your question so far, I didn't need to use type erasure.

First, we define the generic hierarchy that we need:

```
// implemented by your immutable structs
protocol Entity {
}

// Implemented by RealmSwift.Object subclasses
protocol RealmEntity {
    associatedtype EntityType

    init(_ entity: EntityType)
    var entity: EntityType { get }
}

// protocol to define the operations one can perform on a repository
protocol Repository {
    associatedtype EntityType

    func getAll() -> [EntityType]
    func insert(item: EntityType)
}

// A RealmRepository that implements the Repository protocol on top of Realm
class RealmRepository<T>: Repository where T: RealmEntity, T: Object, T.EntityType: Entity {
    typealias RealmEntityType = T

    private let realm = Realm()

    internal func insert(item: T.EntityType) {
        realm.write {
            realm.add(RealmEntityType(item))
        }
    }

    internal func getAll() -> [T.EntityType] {
        return realm.objects(T.self).flatMap { $0.entity }
    }
}
```

Now that we have the infrastructure, we can create an ExpenseRepository to show that all of this stuff compiles:

```
struct Expense: Entity {
    var id: Int
    var amount: Double
}

class RealmExpense: Object, RealmEntity {
    typealias EntityType = Expense

    let id: RealmOptional<Int>
    let amount: RealmOptional<Double>

    required init(_ entity: EntityType) {
        id = RealmOptional(entity.id)
        amount = RealmOptional(entity.amount)
    }

    var entity: Expense {
        return Expense(id: id.value!, amount: amount.value!)
    }
}

var expenseRepository = RealmRepository<RealmExpense>()
```

This may not compile in your project, since I created in a playground that didn't import Realm, but it should give you an idea.

Now, if you want to store an array of repositories of different types, or a variable of type Repository, that's when you'll need type erasure, and have to create an `AnyRepository`.

Comment: So close! So this works for the get method but when trying to initialize a RealmEntityType for the insert method I receive an error "Missing argument label "value: " in call.  It seems it does not pick up the initializer from the RealmEntity protocol and tries to use the Object superclass initializer.

Comment: Searching around a bit for this issue I found this is actually a Swift bug: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/2514  Searching for workarounds.

Comment: Ok, it looks like I found a suitable workaround. Since the expected initializer expects a Dictionary, and I am already using the ObjectMapper library to convert my entities to and from JSON this was not too difficult. 1) Specify that Entity conforms to Mappable, 2) Then, change the insert method to initialize the RealmEntity first, and then set values for keys: 
        let realmItem = RealmEntityType()
        realmItem.setValuesForKeys(item.toJSON())

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the final solution. Do you want to post an answer with the code you ended up with?

Comment: I posted the changes needed to my original post.

Comment: @DaveWeston I find your solution amazing, but I am facing an error on this line:        let expenseRepository = RealmRepository<RealmExpense>()
 "Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class 'RealmTutorial.RealmExpense'".

Answer (score 1):

for all those who are looking into such kind of solution, I have made a sample taking help from the discussions above. I am posting the link for the repo below
https://github.com/Rj707/GenericRealm

Answer (score -1):

I am trying to write a library, you can find it on:

https://github.com/rusito-23/RealmDAO

UPDATE:

The basic idea is to handle all your Realm transactions inside a class called GenericDAO, that has two associated types, one that extends from Object, and another that extends from Transferrable (this way we can handle a copy of the object and not the object itself).

There is also an extra protocol and his method to handle Autoincremental primary keys!

It should be as simple to use as:

```
let movieDAO = GenericDAO<Movie>()

movieDAO.findAll(completion: { /*-- YOUR CODE --*/})
```

You can find more information on the link I sent!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Good job! No worries, the subsequent reviewers will see it and recommend to keep it (this is the standard procedure). Kudos for your responsiveness...